# Per-object singleton

Tags: c++, singleton

*(I tried searching, but you just get a flood of plain singleton explanations.)*

A "normal" singleton guarantees that only one object of a given type exists in the entire program. For example, like this:

```
template <class T>
T& getSingleton()
{
  static T instance;
  return instance;
}
```

I am looking for a way to have no more than one object of a given type `T` *in any given object* of type `O`. That is, something like this:

```
class O
{
  // getSingleton<SomeType>() always returns the same SomeType reference for the same instance of O.
  // getSingleton<SomeType>() returns different SomeType references for different instances of O.
  template<class T>
  T& getSingleton() { /* ??? */ }
};
```

It is totally fine if all `T` are required to derive from a certain base class (which is probably required for storing them type-erased in a container inside `O`), say, `TBase`. However, the set of `T` we care about is open (i.e. not known at the point where `O` is defined), hence member variables are not a solution.

There is of course the more or less straightforward solution of storing e.g. a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TBase>>` and implementing `getSingleton<T>` by attempting a `dynamic_cast` on each element. But I wonder if there is a more elegant approach that does not take linear time.

Comment: Basically, you want each instance of `O` to have up to 1 instance of each possible `T`? If so, then you should drop the singleton terminology. Your question is unrelated to singletons at all and it distracts from the actual question.

Comment: It sounds like you want a normal, bog-standard, run-of-the-mill *member variable*.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux In discussing our use case, different people have all described this idea as a "per-object singleton", unprompted. But I'm open to describing it in a different way and/or having a different title. I just don't know how to explain it differently. "No more than one object per type per object" is woefully incomprehensible.

Comment: @Galik The set of allowable `T` is not closed. So no, a member variable does not do it.

Comment: @SergeBallesta You dropped the `template` part. It should work for an open set of `T`. I have edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: I still don't understand how what you want differs from a *member variable*.

Comment: @Galik Does the edit clarify the problem?

Comment: I think I see more what you are saying now. Are you saying the *type* of such an object won't be known until the program is run? I mean the member function code that uses the object will determine at least a fixed range of possible types won't it?

Comment: `std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::any>` ?

Comment: A `std::vector` needn't take linear time if you retain the index to access the object directly.

Comment: @MaxLanghof If "per-object singleton" has any meaning in your team, it is purely by convention. If it works for you, it's fine if you keep using it but to anyone else it is a meaningless contradiction similar to "per-object static member". This might be why other users here are suggesting straight data member, the "singleton" and "per object" just cancel each other out. Having said that, this is a pretty specific problem and I can't suggest a better name. You may as well keep using "per object singleton" internally but I would suggest not trying to label it here. It will confuse readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library provides `std::type_index` which can be used to effectively associated a unique value to every type. This type is designed to be usable as a key for associative containers. A `std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::any>` can be used to contain a collection of any types. And the since knowing the original type of any element in that map requires knowing the original type (to construct the right `std::type_index` key) it should always be possible to successfully `any_cast` the value.

Here is an example implementation ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/r1bvnhGPG)) :

```
#include <any>
#include <typeindex>
#include <unordered_map>
    
class O
{
public:
    template<class T>
    T& getSingleton()
    { 
        // Get a unique key for the type `T`
        const auto key = std::type_index(typeid(T));

        // Check if the element already exists
        // If it doesn't, construct it in place
        // In either case, returns an iterator to the object
        auto[iter, unused] = members.try_emplace(key, std::in_place_type<T>);

        // Get a reference to the value using its original type
        return std::any_cast<T&>(iter->second);
    }    

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::any> members;
};
```

And the usage looks like :

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    O o;

    // Will value initialize an `int`
    int & i = o.getSingleton<int>();
    
    // `i` and `j` refer to the same object
    int & j = o.getSingleton<int>();
    std::cout << i << ' ' << j << '\n';

    // Changing `i` changes `j`
    i = 42;
    std::cout << i << ' ' << j << '\n';
}
```

The only requirements that this solution imposes on`T` is that it is default constructible and destructible.

Comment: `emplace` already does the find-and-early-return internally (hence the bool). There are also constructors for `pair` and `any` that can allow initializing `T` in place. Everything from the declaration of `iter` to the end of the `if` can be rewritten as: `auto[iter, _unused] = members.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::tie(key), std::tuple{std::in_place_type<T>});`  https://wandbox.org/permlink/fTZnUW1xn55F7imG

Comment: And even that can be shorter... `auto[iter, _unused] = members.try_emplace(key, std::in_place_type<T>);` - And no `T` is ever copied or moved.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks. I didn't know about `std::in_place_type<T>`. Does it value initialize the object held by the constructed `any`? When I try it, I see it zero initializes an `int` but I can't find documentation that it is guaranteed.

Comment: It's claimed to *"direct-non-list-initializing"* the `T` from any extra `Args`.... I take it to mean it will indeed value initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could be used:

```
#include <map>     // for map
#include <memory>  // for unique_ptr
#include <tuple>   // for ignore, tie

class O {
 private:
  template <class T>
  static void index(){};
  using obj_ptr = std::unique_ptr<void, void (*)(void*) noexcept>;
  std::map<void (*)(), obj_ptr> instances;

 public:
  template <class T>
  T& getSingleton() {
    auto it = instances.find(index<T>);
    if (it == instances.end()) {
      static constexpr auto deleter =
          +[](void* t) noexcept { delete static_cast<T*>(t); };

      std::tie(it, std::ignore) =
          instances.emplace(std::pair{&index<T>, obj_ptr{new T, deleter}});
    }
    return *static_cast<T*>(it->second.get());
  }
};
```

Comment: The challenge with this solution is the remove elements from `instances` when an instance of `O` is destroyed. Otherwise every instance of `O` will effectively leak each `T` it had.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux hmm. Good point. I'll see if I can solve that.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I tried to fix it. It is similar to your answer, but without `std::any`. You lose the small object optimization, but the codegen is much better. I guess it's a fair trade-off. It also doesn't require RTTI because we don't use `std::type_index`.

Comment: That `index` template is a really interesting take on establishing an order over types, but I think it relies on unspecified behavior (function pointers are only required to be properly comparable with `==` and `!=`, the other comparison operators could have arbitrary non-deterministic results). Although I would expect it to work fine in practice on most implementations.

Comment: @MaxLanghof `std::map` used `std::less`, which is well defined for all pointers. If I am not missing anything, that applies to function pointers too. You can also use `std::unordered_map`, which only needs `std::equal`.